# how to scrolling unroll a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, scroll

For example, I have a matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16
```

I want it to become

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
[3,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
```

How do I do it without using loops?

Comment: What is the rule here?  `nrows - 1` rows at a time? What have you tried?

Comment: @sirallen Why did you delete the post?  It seems to get the expected output

Answer (score 1):

**1) zoo::rollapply**

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(m, 2, function(x) c(t(x)), by.column = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
[3,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
```

**1a)** This would also work giving the same answer:

```
rollapply(c(t(m)), 8, c, by = 4)
```

**2) sapply**  This alternative uses no packages and gives the same answer:

```
t(sapply(1:3, function(i) t(m)[, i + 0:1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could use row selection with `seq`:

```
x <- read.table(text="
1    2    3    4
5    6    7    8
9    10   11   12
13   14   15   16", header=FALSE)

cbind(x[seq(1, nrow(x)-1, by=1),],
      x[seq(2, nrow(x), by=1),])

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
2  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
3  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 0):

algebraically, it can be done by multiplying the following matrix

```
m <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4, byrow=T)
cbind(diag(3), 0, 0, diag(3)) %*% (diag(2) %x% m)
```

Though I think G. Grothendieck's approach is by far the best.